Azure VPN Client on 24.04-LTS
Does anyone have experience with Azure VPN Client(Microsoft Entra ID Authentication) for Ubuntu 24.04-LTS?
The documentation from Microsoft (dated October 2024) states that supported Ubuntu's are  20.04 and 22.04.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/point-to-site-entra-vpn-client-linux
Henning Jansen,
Egersund - Norway

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

I have not been able to connect to the resource behind the VPN. The client is working on Ubuntu 24.04, the logs and the routed IP traffic indicate that the VPN is being established. However, traffic seem to be routed on the default public IP instead of the tunneled IP.
